# Await ethereum transaction in javascript by only knowing the transaction hash

Tags: web3js, blockchain, transactions, ethers.js, ethereumjs

Is there a way to check if a transaction was mined/it's being mined by only knowing the transaction hash?
I'm using ethers.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

Assuming you have an ethers RPC provider setup, you can use [`provider.waitForTransaction`](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/providers/provider/#Provider-waitForTransaction) to await the transaction based on it's hash.

You may also include an optional desired number of block confirmations and a timeout in that function call if so desired.

```js
try {
  const transactionReceipt = provider.waitForTransaction(transactionHash);
  console.log("Transaction confirmed", transactionReceipt);
} catch (error) {
  console.error("Transaction failed", error);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I thought that was working only if you initialized the transaction in the same context